# CSS drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I want to make a drop down list with nice buttons that are long as the screen (compatible with more screens)....

I will use 3 images (left , middle and right) ... something like this (of course, smaller):

[image]

The middle part will repeat itself to "fill" the button. I want to get something like this:

[image]

There is no example with 3 images, all I could found is only 2 images.

Comment: It helps if you show what you already have in HTML and CSS

Comment: Looking at your previous questions, there's a good chance this only needs to work in Mobile Safari. Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Take a look at [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Comment: Just wondering.. why 3 images?

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

**html:**

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="inner">text</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.clear {clear: both; height: 0px; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;}

.button {
    padding-right: 15px; /* right image width */
    background: url('right_image.jpg') no-repeat right top;
    height: 20px; /* images height */
}

.button .left {
    background: url('left_image.jpg') no-repeat right top;
    width: 15px; /* left image width */
    height: 20px; /* images height */
    float: left;
}
.button .inner {
    height: 20px; /* images height */
    background: url('middle_image.jpg') repeat-x right top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YBmAd/1/)

Comment: That's unsemantic usage of html. The 'button' is either a button or a link.

Comment: @Damien I've used `<div>`s just to show an example using block elements

Comment: great example but the button will extend only if the title extend

Comment: @kevin that's not true ... the example is using `block` element so it will always take 100% of the free space

Comment: thanks, you right, but i dont want to waste the rest of the space if I only put one single word. how can I resize the button which depends on the size of the text?

Comment: @kevin then you could use `inline` elements

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

That's html:

```
<button>
  <span><span> MENU </span></span>
</button>
```

You should place all parts of your image in a very wide none-transparent(for transparent png method is harder a little bit) PNG(like it looks on design), trimmed to the image content. (one image wouldn't increase size much, but will make less http request to server). It called sprite.

```
button {  }
button span { 
  padding:0 0 0 25px; 
  background:url('image.png') left 0; 
  display:inline-block; 
  height:25px; 
  line-height:25px; 
}
button span span { 
  padding:0 25px 0 0; 
  background:url('image.png') right 0; 
}
```

That's it. Of course you should place your image name, and your values of padding, height and line-height.

Comment: this looks great, but I need to do that with three images. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are no examples with 3 images because you don't need 3 images. Create a small right images (like you have posted above) and create a left + center image with your maximum width (let's say 800px). Set the left sided / background image on a `<li>` and hook the right side up to the `<a>`.

```
<li>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Of course an even beter way is to use CSS3 for rounded corners (border-radius) and a simple repeated background image (gradient).

Comment: This way you will have at least 10px wide same-color-as-button-element that won't be clickable

Comment: Also the size of the image in kilobytes will be a lot bigger and that's not what kevin asked

Comment: sorry, I needed to use 3 images. :(

Comment: Doing it @Damien's way is the better way to do it. Why do you "need" to use 3 images? Be solution-oriented not path-oriented, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - this uses 3 background images which isn't compatible with IE8 and below, but you could use two inner divs to give you three containers and put one image in each - note the bottom image is listed last.

```
nav {
     height:75px; /* height of graphic elements */
      background:
        url(images/left_end.png) no-repeat 0px 0px,
        url(images/right_end.png) no-repeat right top,
        url(images/center.png); /* this images repeats */
}
```